# Can an NFA have multiple accepting states?

Tags: finite-automata

I am currently preparing for exam. While studying Finite Automata, i got confused. I know a DFA can have multiple accepting states, but can an NFA also have multiple accepting states?

Answer (score 6):

Whenever one is in doubt about central notions, one must consult the definitions of them. You should do this yourself (I assume that you have a textbook at your disposal).

Below is Definition 1.37 from *Introduction to the Theory of Computation* by Michael Sipser:

A nondeterministic finite automaton is a 5-tuple $(Q,\Sigma,\Delta,q_0,F)$, where

1. $Q$ is a finite set of states,
2. $\Sigma$ is a finite alphabet,
3. $\delta: Q \times \Sigma_{\epsilon} \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(Q)$ is
   the transition function,
4. $q_0 \in Q$ is the start state, and
5. $F \subseteq Q$ is the set of accept states.

Item 5 tells us that $F$ is just a set of states, which means that it can be the empty set, a singleton set or a set with several states as elements.